# How do I realize a Shell Script that keeps track of how long the keyboard has not been used ?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, cron, keyboard

Is it possible to write a script that counts the time between two pressed keys, so that one could put a script into the crontab that checks if the keyboard had not been for longer than a certain time and if so to execute `shutdown -h` now .

Comment: Use `w` and idle time in it

Comment: If you've got a GUI running it's likely you just need to enable Power Saving in its control panel settings